# How can I create symmetric edges in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I would like the edges between two nodes to be symmetric about a horizontal line. For example, this code:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    s [style=invisible]
    A [peripheries=2]
    D [peripheries=2]
    B [peripheries=2]
    s -> A
    A -> C [label="1"]
    C -> D [label="0"]
    D -> C [label="1"]
    A -> B [label="0"]
}
```

Produces this graph:

[image: non-symmetric edges]

I would prefer the edges between `C` and `D` to look more like this:

[image: symmetric edges]

Is there a way to get Graphviz to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a third edge and make the middle one invisible:

```
C -> D [label="0"];
D -> C [style=invis];
D -> C [label="1"];
```

Comment: That worked after I added `arrowhead=none` to get rid of the phantom arrow head. No offense, but adding invisible elements to force layout changes seems kinda kludgy. I was expecting something in the language to achieve this.

Comment: No offense taken :-) I agree with your opinion about invisible elements, and I'd prefer to put up with the first graph than adding invisible edges. Unfortunately that's the only way I know to achieve this. The problem with arrowhead probably depends on the exact version of graphiz used - I didn't have to add this.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to spend some time weighing asymmetry against kludginess.